# How to string xinit and xsetroot in one line?

Tags: linux, xserver

My goal is to show a solid color background while inside xinit without the xterm, a full screen solid background will do.
I realize I can use xsetroot -solid color for this purpose but the xterm still exist there.
I also know that I could run a full screen video inside xinit using "`xinit ./mplayer *mp4`"

I tried to use the same workaround for xsetroot

```
xinit /usr/bin/xsetroot -solid green
```

but this doesn't work.

Anyone knows any workaround to achieve my goal mentioned above?

Thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xinit ; DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xsetroot -solid green
```

Or create a `.xinitrc` with

```
/usr/bin/xsetroot -solid green &
```

in it.

HTH

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, the error is /usr/bin/xsetroot: unable to open display :0